# Equivalent of "this coming from"

Tags: vocabulaire, formulation-idiomatique

For example:

> Haha, that's the worst idea you've ever had!
>
> What?! This coming from a guy who thought [blah blah] was a good idea?!

Is there any way to translate the 'this coming from' into French? If not it's fine - I was going to settle with something like:

> Quoi?! Mais c'était toi qui a pensé que [blah blah] était une bonne idée!

Comment: "Venant de quelqu'un qui pensait que... ?!" would be fine I guess if I understood the initial meaning.

Comment: Yep totally agree with Manu here. +1
Literally that would be : " Quoi ?! Venant d'un gars qui pensait que [blab blah] était une bonne idée !"
You should post your answer @Manu310 :)

Comment: I don’t know if any of the following is idiomatic, but maybe it could be of some help: … I’d add something to capture the notion of “That’s a good one” and “especially”, and use either “venant de” (as suggested by @Manu310); “de la part de”; or even a combination of the two (venant de la part de) (and to better capture “guy”, maybe use “mec”): ….”Quoi? Elle est bonne, celle-là, surtout venant de la part d’un/du mec qui trouvait bonne l’idée de (voter pour Trump [for example])!”

Comment: Quoi?! Mais c'était toi qui a pensé que is the best so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

> De la part de quelqu'un qui pensait que ... ?

In spoken language, "*venant de la part de*" could get abbreviated to "*de la part de*".

Comment: It seems that 'De la part de' is used quite a lot actually. I'm going with this answer. Thanks everyone.

Comment: You also easily have "De la part de *celui* qui ...." ("Coming from *the* guy who ..."),

Answer (score 3):

Frank's answer is good; other alternatives with possibly other shades of meaning:

> Quand on pense que c'est toi qui ... !
>
> Et dire que c'est toi qui ... !

Answer (score 3):

As Ise proposed me to do it in the comments to your question, here is my proposition :

"Venant de quelqu'un qui pensait que... ?!"

Of course, regarding other answers, this is a very spoken form, but from what I understand of your question, I think this fits perfecly :)